# I want to connect database that saves data from the user that he sends in watson assistant

Tags: database, ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am building a chatbot where I try to collect information from the user like his name, email, phone number... and I want to store them in a database. either google sheets or any database I can connect it to. is there a way to connect database to Watson assistant?

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Db2onCloud

I tried the tutorial on this website but I reached a dead end

Can I link google sheets to watson assistant?

Comment: Check out this tutorial: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/solution-tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-slack-chatbot-database-watson. It is also available from the Watson Assistant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

A general answer to connect to any third-party tool is to use the Custom Extensions feature provided by Watson Assistant.

official docs: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-call-extension
some blogs:

- [Connect to Backend Systems and Third-Party APIs with Ease Thanks to
  Watson Assistant Extensions!](https://medium.com/ibm-watson/connect-to-backend-systems-and-third-party-apis-with-ease-thanks-to-watson-assistant-extensions-6d6150eaeba)
- [Extending Watson Assistant Part 1:
  Connecting to CRM Systems](https://medium.com/ibm-watson/extending-watson-assistant-part-1-connecting-to-crm-systems-80deda33a68e)
- [Watson Assistant: Connecting Customer
  Care to IBM Cloud Functions APIs](https://medium.com/ibm-watson/watson-assistant-connecting-customer-care-to-ibm-cloud-functions-apis-298d777f72e2)
- [From cURL to an Extension under
  5 minutes!](https://medium.com/ibm-watson/from-curl-to-an-extension-under-5-minutes-c4662d95c21a)
- [Extensions Made Easy with Watson Assistant Starter
  Kits](https://medium.com/ibm-watson/extensions-made-easy-with-watson-assistant-starter-kits-6b177f624697)

Answer (score 0):

Watson Assistant has a "Logging Extension" feature that allows you to hook to a REST API.

It can be found by going to environments, then clicking the cog.

More details can be found here:

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-webhook-log

As an example this is a cloud function that connects to Cloudant database (this is not production level code).

```
import requests
import json

database_name = 'wa_demo_logs'

# apikey and url you get from the Cloudant credentials. 
apikey = 'API_KEY'
url = 'URL'

def get_bearer_token():
    access_token = None
    iam_data = {
        'grant_type': 'urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey',
        'apikey': apikey
    }

    response = requests.post('https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token', data=iam_data)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        access_token = response.json()['access_token']

    return access_token



def main(data):

    # Beyond a demo you would need to cache this and check that it expires after an hour. 
    token = get_bearer_token()


    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'
    }
    
    # To scale down you can just  data['payload']
    data = { 'item':data }

    response = requests.post(f'{url}/{database_name}', data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

    return response.json()
```